# GCDAsyncSocket reading long text partially: iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, gcdasyncsocket

When a long text string is sent using `GCDAsyncSocket`, `readDataWithTimeOut` is called multiple times at the receiving end, but the data received is inconsistent, i.e. the same text is received but the `NSData` is different. What could be the possible reason for the discrepancy? Please let me know as I have very little knowledge of `GCDAsyncSocket`.

```
- (void)writeData:(NSData *)data {   
    [self.asyncSocket writeData:data withTimeout:-1 tag:1];
}

#pragma mark - GCDAsyncSocket Delegate Methods -
- (void)socketDidDisconnect:(GCDAsyncSocket *)sock withError:(NSError *)err {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:KSOCKET_MANAGER_REMOVAL
                                                        object:self
                                                      userInfo:nil];

}

- (void)socketDidCloseReadStream:(GCDAsyncSocket *)sock {

}

- (void)socket:(GCDAsyncSocket *)sock didWriteDataWithTag:(long)tag {

}

- (void)socket:(GCDAsyncSocket *)sock didReadData:(NSData *)data withTag:(long)tag {
    DDLogInfo(@"SOCKET DID READ DATA:%@:%@",self.asyncSocket,self.contactJID);
    [sock readDataWithTimeout:-1 tag:0];
    if (data!=nil)
      [self loadMessageWithData:data];
}

#pragma mark - Private Methods -
- (void)loadMessageWithData:(NSData *)encryptedData {
NSLog(@"DATA RECEIVED");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this

```
socket.readDataToData(getNsData(), withTimeout: -1, tag: 1)
```

instead of

```
socket.readDataWithTimeout(1, tag: 0)
```

function used-

```
private func getNsData()-> NSData{
        return NSData(bytes: "#####", length: 5)
    }
```

And ask server guy to append this "#####" at the end of response

//Local socket gets connected to remote socket

```
func socket(socket : GCDAsyncSocket, didConnectToHost host:String, port p:UInt16)

{

    println("Connected to \(host) on port \(p).")

    socket.readDataToData(getNsData(), withTimeout: -1, tag: 2)

}

//Some message from remote socket

func socket(socket : GCDAsyncSocket, didReadData data:NSData, withTag tag:UInt16)

{

    var response = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as! String

    let stringLength = count(response) // Since swift1.2 `countElements` became `count`

    let substringIndex = stringLength - count("#####")

    var servResWithoutHash = response.substringToIndex(advance(response.startIndex, substringIndex))

    println("Updated response  \(servResWithoutHash)")



    if let action = getTheCommand(servResWithoutHash){

        println("COMMAND ==  \(action)")

    socket.readDataToData(getNsData(), withTimeout: -1, tag: 2)

}

//Notifies when socket gets disconnected

func socketDidDisconnect(sock: GCDAsyncSocket!, withError err: NSError!) {

    println("Socket did disconnect with error \(err?.description)");
}
```

Comment: Basically, I am using XMPP Frameworks which internally uses GCDAsyncSocket Class. I did change the way you described. I came across two issues:1. Either the Texts are now getting transfered the second time 2. Still receives chunks of data and not complete data. Could you let me know what needs to be done. I have also modified my question where I have added the code for it.